# Android: What does this warning mean?

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I have a button with a few sound effects. When I click the button, nothing happens. No sound is played, but no force close either. The Debugger is giving me this warning:

"SoundPool - Sample 1 not READY"
"SoundPool - Sample 2 not READY" etc...

**Le Code:**

```
package com.andrew.finnandjake;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Soundboard extends Activity{
private SoundManager mSoundManager;
private int next = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
mSoundManager.addSound(0,R.raw.finn_algebraic);
mSoundManager.addSound(1,R.raw.finn_allaboardthekuckletrain);
mSoundManager.addSound(2,R.raw.finn_iminmyelement);
mSoundManager.addSound(3,R.raw.finn_shmowzow);

Button SoundButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
SoundButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
    mSoundManager.playSound(next);
    next++;
    if(next>3)
      next=0;
  }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds take a while to load. You can use a `SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener` to find out when they're ready. (Android 2.2+ only)